# how to set a deferred on ajax with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, jquery-deferred

let me start with some code:

```
function sendAjax(data, type)
{
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        url : rest + type,
        data : data,

    });
}


$.when(sendAjax(someData, 'url')).then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //undefined
});

$.when(sendAjax(someOtherData, 'url')).then(function(data){
    console.log(data); //undefined
});
```

the issue i'm having is that `data` comes in as undefined

if i use `success` in the `$.ajax` the data comes in fine

The main idea here is that i should write the `sendAjax()` method once and use it through the application, but i don't think i set it up properly

ant ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise return by `$.ajax()` from `sendAjax`

```
function sendAjax(data, type)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "jsonp",
        url : rest + type,
        data : data,

    });
}
```